# Measurability of random measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ be a probability space and $X$ be a Polish space. Let $Prob(X)$ be the collection of Borel-probability measures on $X$, and let it be equipped with the weak-convergence topology.

Let $f:\Omega\times \mathscr{B}_X\rightarrow [0,1]$ be a function such that $f^A:\Omega\rightarrow [0,1]$ is measurable for all $A\in \mathscr{B}_X$ and $f_w$ is a measure for all $w\in \Omega$.

Define $R(w)(A):=f(w,A)$. Then, $R:\Omega\rightarrow Prob(X)$ is a function.

**Question 1**: Is $R$ measurable? ($Prob(X)$ is equipped with the Borel sigma algebra induced by the topology of weak convergence)

Now, for a given $A$, define the evaluation map $h_A(\mu):=\mu(A)$ for all $\mu\in Prob(X)$.

**Question 2**: Is $h_B:Prob(X)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ measurable?

Of course $h_B$ need not be continuous by Portmanteau theorem. However, since $X$ is Polish, Borel probabilities measure on $X$ are inner regular. Hence, one can may approximate $h_B$ by measurable functions. However, I cannot see how to fill the details.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That question does not make sense unless you have a sigma algebra on $Prob(X)$. Do you mean the Borel sigma algebra that is generated by all open sets?

Comment: @amsmath Yes! Right.

Comment: Well, at least for the basis sets $B_{A,a} = \{\mu : \mu(A)<a\}$ you have $R^{-1}(B_{A,a})\in\mathscr F$. But I guess you know that already.